# Can cmvision run with multiple cameras on the same robot?

Tags: ros, multiple, cmvision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have the cmvision package working with two different camaras, but when I try to bring up both of them simultaneously, the initial process (doesn't matter which one I bring up) dies.

To resolve this, I tried renaming the node.   Both processes will then come up, but I only get message data (/blobs) from the instance I launch first.  (I have two launch files)

Any idea why this might be happening and if there is a workaround?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233191/can-cmvision-run-with-multiple-cameras-on-the-same-robot?/) by [toddwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/25891/toddwf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the nearest I can tell, the answer is no.   A workaround is to add another machine to process data for the other webcam.

---

per comments below, <del>workspaces</del> *namespaces* enable this

---

Originally posted by [toddwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/25891/toddwf/) with karma: 16 on 2016-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-15**:
Can't you run both instances under different namespaces? With some suitable topic remapping, you should then be able to provide each instance their own input and output streams as well. Running multiple instances is actually a common use case.

**Comment by [toddwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/25891/toddwf/) on 2017-01-18**:
thanks...I discovered namespaces after I wrote this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-18**:
So would you now change your answer? Because your current answer would seem to be wrong.

**Comment by [toddwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/25891/toddwf/) on 2017-01-18**:
updated original